# How to reference Button from xaml in ViewModel(c#) Xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to implement my own lockscreen in my xamarin app. I have created the numpad as below:

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid Padding="0,0,0,10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="alpaca.png" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding PincodeMasked}" FontFamily="Lato-Bold" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="80" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Padding="40,0,30,0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Image="num1.png" Command="{Binding NumberCommand}" CommandParameter="1" BackgroundColor="#00FFFFFF" />
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Image="num2.png" Command="{Binding NumberCommand}" CommandParameter="2" BackgroundColor="#00FFFFFF" />
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Image="num3.png" Command="{Binding NumberCommand}" CommandParameter="3" BackgroundColor="#00FFFFFF" />
            <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Image="num4.png" Command="{Binding NumberCommand}" CommandParameter="4" BackgroundColor="#00FFFFFF" />
            <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Image="num5.png" Command="{Binding NumberCommand}" CommandParameter="5" BackgroundColor="#00FFFFFF" />
            <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Image="num6.png" Command="{Binding NumberCommand}" CommandParameter="6" BackgroundColor="#00FFFFFF" />
            <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Image="num7.png" Command="{Binding NumberCommand}" CommandParameter="7" BackgroundColor="#00FFFFFF" />
            <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Image="num8.png" Command="{Binding NumberCommand}" CommandParameter="8" BackgroundColor="#00FFFFFF" />
            <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Image="num9.png" Command="{Binding NumberCommand}" CommandParameter="9" BackgroundColor="#00FFFFFF" />
            <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Image="num0.png" Command="{Binding NumberCommand}" CommandParameter="0" BackgroundColor="#00FFFFFF" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

In the ViewModel I want to do something like this

```
public PinLoginPageModel()
    {

        NumberCommand = new Command(NumpadToNumber);
    }

    void NumpadToNumber(object obj)
    {
        if(Button.CommandParameter == 0)
        {
            PincodeMasked = "0";
        }
    }
```

I want to convert each button click to a corresponding value, however I am getting an error at Button.CommandParameter saying it needs to have an object reference. How can I reference this to the button in the XAML code?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe use obj.CommandParameter instead of Button.CommandParameter

Comment: If I do that, it says 'object' does not contain a definition for CommandParameter

Comment: you need to cast object to button type like this ((Button)obj).CommandParameter or you can follow my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your view mode code like below:

```
public PinLoginPageModel()
    {

        NumberCommand = new Command<string>(NumpadToNumber);
    }

    void NumpadToNumber(string obj)
    {
        if(obj == "0")
        {
            PincodeMasked = "0";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void NumpadToNumber(object parameter)
{
    if (parameter != null && parameter.ToString() == "0")
    {
        PincodeMasked = "0";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your view model like this:

```
public PinLoginPageModel()
{

    NumberCommand = new Command<object>(NumpadToNumber);
}

void NumpadToNumber(object obj)
{
    if((obj as int) == 0)
        PincodeMasked = "0";/
}
```